# computations that take a lot of time

Tags: synonyms

What is another alternative to "computations that are time consuming"?
I've heard the expression "computationally expensive" but I am not sure whether it refers to the timespan of the simulation or if the Memory is also included.
I am not very technical, I'm still learning.
I would very much appreciate it if you go easy on me.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The buzzword is these are *[computationally] [**intractable**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory#Intractability) problems.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers, noted. Thank you ^_^

Comment: It may not be exactly right for your context. Generally speaking, those "intractable" problems don't *actually* consume compute power, because we don't try to process them anyway (since we know that there's no chance of getting to an "answer" with current technology).

Comment: Yes, got you. However, I've just added another term to my vocabulary :D

Comment: Are you talking about mathematical calculations which are inherently difficult (like the Travelling Salesman Problem) or about calculations which consist of thousands of relatively simple steps (like the annual accounts for a large business)? You might need different terms (not to mention computer systems) for these.

Comment: No I am talking about finite elements simulations using GetDp that take a lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be interested in the term [**time complexity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity). Your

> computations that are time consuming

could be phrased as

> computations with high time complexity

If you want to refer to resources more generally, use [**complexity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity). Then you can say

> computations with high complexity

which refers to the use of resources, not the difficulty of any mathematics. But quite often, the unqualified *complexity* is taken to mean just its *time* complexity.

Comment: Understood. Thank you!

Comment: And what about the opposite? Do I say, I want to move from a timely complex model to a timely light model?

Comment: That would be **low** time complexity. BTW [*timely*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/timely) means something else.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you for the explanation :)